# How to use bounded generic type with stream and single object

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create one converter from DTO to Entity and Entity to DTO with bounded generic type.

```
public interface GenericConverter<D extends IDTO, E extends IEntity> {

    public E createFrom(D dto);

    public D createFrom(E entity);

    default List createFromEntities(final Collection<? extends IEntity> entities) {
        return entities.stream()
                .map(this::createFrom)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    default List createFromDtos(final Collection<IDTO> dtos) {
        return dtos.stream()
                .map(this::createFrom)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Here is the some piece of code, where IDTO and IEntity are two marker interface. So I do not want to allow any object where only that inherit these interface. 
Single conversion working fine but with stream it gives following error.

```
The type GenericConverter<D,E> does not define createFrom(IDTO) that is applicable here
The type GenericConverter<D,E> does not define createFrom(capture#1-of ? extends IEntity) that is applicable here
}
```

Could someone help me to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: `default List createFromEntities(final Collection<? extends E> entities)`

Comment: Also do not return raw types like `List` - try to generify that.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by using the same generic types `D` and `E` for the collection parameter:

```
public interface GenericConverter<D extends IDTO, E extends IEntity>
{
    E createFrom(D dto);
    D createFrom(E entity);

    default List<D> createFromEntities(final Collection<E> entities)
    {
        return entities.stream()
                       .map(this::createFrom)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    default List<E> createFromDtos(final Collection<D> dtos)
    {
        return dtos.stream()
                   .map(this::createFrom)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: wildcard could also be applied to parameters in those methods as they act as producers so in first case  `? extends E` and in the second method `? extends D`, if I am not mistaken.